# Which step fails if we would assume $F=(a,b) \subset ℝ$ in the Heine-Borel theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a question about the theorem: "Every k-cell in $ℝ^k$ is compact". I think it is quite a hard proof, and when I was thinking about it I don't understand the following:

Suppose $F$ is not $k$-cell, suppose $F$ is is an open set, or to make it more simple, suppose $F$ is the open interval $(a,b) ∈ ℝ$. Of course, this prove shouldn't work for $(a,b)$ but I don't see why this is true. Which step fails if we would assume $F=(a,b) \subset ℝ$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the $F_n$ are *open*, and $F_n \supset F_{n+1}$, then $\bigcup_n F_n$ isn't necessarily non-empty. But you need it to be non-empty, otherwise you don't arrive at a contradiction since there's no point $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The first one.

Without lost of generality, you can assume your open interval to be $(0,1)$. Then the following

$$
(1/n, 1-1/n) \ ,  \qquad n \geq 3
$$

is an open cover of $(0,1)$ whithout any finite subcover.

Comment: But the question states "Asume that there's a cover *without* a finite subcover"... So there's no problem there yet.

Comment: From my point of view, it's quite different to begin a "proof" saying: "Assume that there's a cover without a finite subcover...", than to say: "*Here is* a cover without a finite subcover." End of the question.  :-)

Comment: But the question wasn't whether or not $(a,b)$ is compact, but where *exactly* the proof fails. That's IMHO a valid question, and it's often quite instructive to analyze where exactly a proof fails if you weaken the requirements. Your answer offers a reason as to *why* the proof fails for $(a,b)$, but not *where*, which I feel begs the question.